# Swift Dismiss navigation controller after prepare for segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have the following schema:
[image]
The controller in the upper right corner is SelectAlbumVC

The controller in the lower left corner is AddPhotoVC

In SelectAlbumVC i have this code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let destination = segue.destination as? AddPhotoPostVC
        else { fatalError("unexpected view controller for segue") }
    guard let cell = sender as? AlbumListCells else { fatalError("unexpected cell for segue") }

    switch SegueIdentifier(rawValue: segue.identifier!)! {
    case .showAllPhotos:
        destination.fetchResult = allPhotos
        destination.headerTitleBtnString = cell.allPhotoTitle.text!
    case .showCollection:
        // get the asset collection for the selected row
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)!
        let collection: PHCollection
        switch Section(rawValue: indexPath.section)! {
        case .smartAlbums:
            collection = smartAlbums.object(at: indexPath.row)
        case .userCollections:
            collection = userCollections.object(at: indexPath.row)
        default: return // not reached; all photos section already handled by other segue
        }

        // configure the view controller with the asset collection
        guard let assetCollection = collection as? PHAssetCollection
            else { fatalError("expected asset collection") }
        destination.fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection, options: nil)
        destination.assetCollection = assetCollection
        destination.headerTitleBtnString = cell.collectionTitle.text!
        destination.isComingFromSelectAlbum = true
    }
}
```

so basically when i click on a cell the segue will be executed and the data passed to AddPhotoVC.
My issue is that when the segue is executed the navigation controller associated with SelectAlbumVC is not dismissed and so when clicking the dismissing button on the AddPhotoVC SelectAlbumVC is presented again (it's the last controller in the stack).

Is there a way to dismiss the navigation controller when the prepare for segue is called?
I've tried to add the the bottom

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
```

but it does not work.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you're adding another segue back to AddPhotoVC.  So if while your app was running and you clicked the "Debug View Hierarchy" (down by the debugger controls in Xcode) you'd see that you now have another AddPhotoVC on top of the original one.

Instead of performing a segue from SelectPhotoVC to AddPhotoVC you may want to consider performing an Unwind Segue instead.  This way you could pass the values you want and all the previous VCs would be dismissed.

Comment: if i open the "Debug View Hierarchy" i see a NavivgationController and inside the SelectAlbumVC. Not sure about the unwind segue because i am new to swift and i have never seen them, But if this is te only solution i will look into it and try to figure it out... thx...

Comment: @Marco If you have a version of this project you can throw up on GitHub, I can show you how to wire it up.

Comment: here's the link... https://github.com/coty10/photo is a demo app for the photo part.. thank you!! i do really appreciate.. i will look into it to learn it better...

Answer (score 2):

You are using (multiple) two `UINavigationController`. That means you are `presenting` the second screen instead of `pushing` it.

Now, you mentioned that `popToRootViewController` does not work, that's because again the two screens have two different `UINavigationController`. You should `dismiss` the second screen rather than `popping` it, because you presented it.

Know the different between pushing/show and presenting viewControllers.

Push/Show --- Pop.

Present --- Dismiss.

Instead of this `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)`

Use this:

```
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    // completion, do something or make it nil.
})
```

Comment: you mean to put all the segue code inside the completion handler? if i do so it seems that the data are not passed. I update the data in viewWill appear inside the addPhotoVc

Comment: @Marco if, from AddPhotoVC, you call `self.navigationController?.dismiss`, it will dismiss back to whatever was active before `SelectAlbumVC` was shown

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ which is the SelectAlbumVC since it is not dismissed after the segue...

Comment: Marco, hope Causaelity can help you out as I do not have time today to look into your project. But here's the thing, you do not need to connect back the second screen into your first screen using segue. If tomorrow I have time and you still haven't figured what you want to do out, let me know.

Comment: @Glenn thx... i have tried and i actually solved it :) i have added the code in the github repository (link in the other comment) with the working code... so if anybody need it they can download it. Thank you!

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ yes and it wasn't wrking... solution offered by Causaelity works ... :)